# Unclear why bootswatch is not rendering in html

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/flatly/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Image Editor</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-info mb-5">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Online Image Filter</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to use bootswatch and I'm unable to. Do I have it sourced right? I'm currently unable to apply any of its css styles in my html file and I'd like some clarification as to why.

Comment: Your code appears to work. Although I don't have your style.css which may be overwriting some of the classes you're using.

Comment: the styles.css is empty. For reasons I'm not clear on, the bootswatch css styling is not rendering on my end.

Comment: Have you tried hard refreshing the page?

Comment: im running the HTML file from live-server inside VS code.

Comment: I haven't experimented with that extension.  You could try downloading the css file and referencing it locally and see if that makes a difference.